# AngularJS : how to use ng-change in factories?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

My html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-change="change(value)">
</div>
```

My controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    var search;

    $scope.change = function(value) {
        search = value;
    }
}]);
```

It works great.

Now I want to use this function (ng-change) into factory, but I don't know how. So, my controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'MainFactory', function($scope, MainFactory){
    $scope.search = MainFactory.getSearch();
}]);
```

My factory:

```
app.factory('MainFactory', function(){
    var search;

    return {
        getSearch: function() {
            whatMustBeHere.change = function(value) {
                search = value;
            }
            return search;
        }
    }
});
```

Maybe, there is some other way to solve this issue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use getters and setters to save the value in your factory

You can just set the value onChange (Don't forget to inject the factory in your controller)

Like this:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope, MainFactory){

    $scope.search = MainFactory.getSearchValue();

    $scope.change = function(value) {
        MainFactory.setSearchValue(value);
    }
}]);
```

and in your factory

```
app.factory('MainFactory', function(){
    var search;

    return {
        setSearchValue: function(value) {
            this.search = value;
        }

        getSearchValue: function() {
            return this.search;
        }
    }
});
```